# Place tag below long line in numcases

Tags: numbering

For math lines that fill the whole text width, the align environment places the tag below the line. The numcases environment, however, runs the tag into the margin.

Is there a way to get the numcases tag to appear below the line instead of in the margin?

Edit: Based on egreg's suggestion in the comments, I've tried using empheq instead of numcases. With the documentation's suggested syntax for cases-like behavior, overlong lines bump all of the equation numbers below all of the cases, instead of interleaving them.

Examples of the behavior I'm seeing.

1. `align` with a long line places equation numbers below each row within text area:

```
\begin{align}
&AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA && \text{Case A} \\
&BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB && \text{Case B}
\end{align}
```

[image: align]
2. `numcases` with a long line puts equation numbers inline with the rows, making them longer:

```
\begin{numcases}{L=}
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & Case A \\
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & Case B
\end{numcases}
```

[image: numcases]

3. `empheq` with a short line (verifying syntax):

```
\begin{empheq}[left={L=\empheqlbrace}]{align}
&A && \text{Case A} \\
&B && \text{Case B}
\end{empheq}
```

[image: empheq short line]

4. `empheq` with a long line puts all of the equation numbers below the case-like structure:

```
\begin{empheq}[left={L=\empheqlbrace}]{align}
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA && \text{Case A} \\
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB && \text{Case B}
\end{empheq}
```

[image: empheq long line]

Here are all of the examples typeset together for scale:

[image: All examples]

Comment: You might try `empheq` instead of `numcases`. Can you please add an example?

Comment: @egreg. Thanks for pointing out that package. Unless I'm missing something, the way it's implemented, the overflow behavior is to put all of the equation numbers below the case-like structure as a block. I've updated the question with examples.